# how to replace background image with glyphicon in css?

Tags: html, css

Im using a third-party grid in my web app wich defines a sortable icon as a png image. I would like to override it in my style.css file with a glyphicon without changin the third-party source, is it possible?

The third party code:

```
div.column-header-container {
     background: url('column-sortable.png') no-repeat right;
}
```

And my style.css would be something like:

```
div.column-header-container  {
    background: GlyphIconHere no-repeat right;
}
```

I just can find examples using it directly on the html tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you're trying to override is called `background-image`. All you need is an equal or higher specificity selector in your `CSS` (equal if it loads last) and a valid property value. You can do it in stylesheet (`.css` file), in `<style>` tag or in `style=""` attribute.

- `.css` file:

```css
div.column-header-container { 
  background-image: url('http://lorepixel.com/g/400/100');
}
```

- `<style>` tag

```html
<style>
  div.column-header-container { 
    background-image: url('http://lorepixel.com/g/400/100');
  }
</style>
```

- Inline `style=""`

```html
<div style="background-image:url('http://lorepixel.com/g/400/100');"></div>
```

---

Specifically, for `font-awesome`, which seems to be the case, you want to do this:

- <strike>go to [`cheatsheet`](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/)</strike> this no longer works!
- go to fa icon page and get the Unicode ([`example`](http://fontawesome.io/icon/eercast/) = "\f2da")
- add this CSS:

```css
div.column-header-container {
  background-image: none;
}
div.column-header-container:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome', fantasy;
  content: '\f2da';
}
```

You will also need to specify `font-size`, probably `position:relative` or absolute, depending on use-case and perhaps position using `top`/`left`.
In some cases, adding `fa` class or `fa-2x`, `fa-3x` or `fa-4x` ***to parent*** helps, as it sets some of the properties you otherwise need to set yourself. However, don't count on it having the same size as other sister "natural" `fa-*` icons. You'll need to tame it..

Comment: Thanks, but im using font-awesome and i cannot find how to know the 'url'  of the icon that i want. Its just a .css file in it.

Comment: I'll update with how to do it for fa. It's a bit trickier But you should have specified! :)

Comment: I want to understand. You have fa already loaded in project and want to replace some random image with a fa icon. Is this your case?

Comment: Yes, the path would be something like url('./node_modules/font-awesome/icon')

Comment: If you can't change the `font-family` on the parent item, change it only on the `:before`, it's ok.

Comment: @ggui Have you got this? I updated my answer, cheatsheet no longer displays unicodes.